# Evaluation of trigonometric integrals in PDE $u_t=ku_{xx}-hu$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following second order PDE $u_t=ku_{xx}-hu$, where $0<x<l,~t>0$ and $h$ is a positive constant. The PDE has **BCs**, $u_x=0$ at $x=0,~x=l$ and **ICs**, $u(x,0)=x$. I have worked so far that $$u_n(x,t)=A_n\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})\exp(-(\frac{n^2\pi^2 k}{l^2}+h)).$$

The next step is to use the **IC** and get

$$u(x,0)=A_0+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})=x.$$ The above we multiply by $\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{l})$ and integrate, and so we have

\begin{align}
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\int^{l}_{0} \cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx
&=\int^{l}_{0} x\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx\\
&=\frac{l^2}{\pi^2 m^2}(\cos(mx)-1)
\end{align}
But I am struggling to calculate the part $\int^{l}_{0}\cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx$ which using a calculator will get $$\frac{l(n-m)\sin(\pi(n+m))+l(n+m)\sin(\pi(n-m))}{2\pi(n^2-m^2)}$$ which I think is equal to zero since both $n,m$ are positive integers.

Should I integrate taking fixed values of $n,m$ which will give $$\int^{l}_{0}\cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx =\frac{l}{2}?$$

If yes, what is the justification behind that?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Your expression is zero when $n\not =m$, but when $n=m$ the denominator is also $0$ so you effectively have a $0/0$ limit. You can for example use L'Hopitals rule on this to get the right result out of your expression: $\lim_{n\to m} \frac{l(n-m)\sin(\pi(n+m))+l(n+m)\sin(\pi(n-m))}{2\pi(n^2-m^2)}$ = $\lim_{n\to m}\frac{l\sin(\pi(n+m))+l\pi(n-m)\cos(\pi(n+m))+l\sin(\pi(n-m))+l\pi(n+m)\cos( \pi (n-m))}{4\pi n}$ = $\frac{l}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have
>
> \begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n\int^{l}_{0} \cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi
>  x}{l}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx &=\int^{l}_{0}
>  x\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx\\ &=\frac{l^2}{\pi^2
>  m^2}(\cos(m\pi)-1) \end{align}

You should observe that the trig functions $\cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi
 x}{l}\bigg)$ are orthogonal. This means that whenever $n\neq m$,

$$\int^{l}_{0} \cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi
 x}{l}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg) dx=0,$$ and when $n=m$,

$$\int^{l}_{0} \cos^2\bigg(\frac{n\pi
 x}{l}\bigg) dx = \frac {l}{2}.$$

With this,

\begin{align}
A_m \frac{l}{2}
&=\frac{l^2}{\pi^2 m^2}(\cos(m \pi)-1)
=\frac{l^2}{\pi^2 m^2}((-1)^m-1)
\end{align} so we can solve for $A_m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I check if the trigonometric functions are orthogonal?

Comment: @johnny09 You have already shown this! you have said "using a calculator will get $$\frac{l(n-m)\sin(\pi(n+m))+l(n+m)\sin(\pi(n-m))}{2\pi(n^2-m^2)}$$ which I think is equal to zero since both $n,m$ are positive integers." That is all you need.

Comment: @johnny09 are you asking how to get this anti-derivative by hand, rather than using a calculator?

Comment: No, I just didn't realize I proved $\int f(x)g(x) dx=0$ which is the inner product of the functions. Now I know how to solve the PDE. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @johnny09 My pleasure. And yes, you were evaluating an inner product.